# How to refer to chained issues e.g. a problem caused by a problem caused by a problem

Tags: idioms

In french, we often refer to `Un problème à tiroirs` or literally `An issue with drawers` any problem that is caused by another unsolved issue which in turn is caused by another issue until to a certain recursion depth.

How can I refer to such problem in English? I seriously doubt that `dawer issue` is the correct idiom.

Comment: Thanks for the approved answer badge! Hope my answer helped!

Comment: Another possibility is using a metaphor like [Russian nesting dolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll#As_metaphor) or an onion - something with many layers, where you peel back one layer only to find another one.

Comment: I like that metaphor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Fixing the leak in the roof *will have a snowball effect*, so I haven't gotten around to fixing it yet.

**Long Answer**

A snowball effect is when things keep building and building, for better or worse.

In this case, fixing the leak in the ceiling might lead to the ceiling caving in, which would lead to having to fix the ceiling, which would lead to having to go to the hardware store and so on and so forth.

(Obviously,) it takes its name from making a snowball where you start with a small ball of snow and keep rolling it and rolling it until it gets bigger and bigger.

Note that depending on the situation, this could be good or bad.

You may also see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_effect) for more information or a(n even more complete,) duplicate answer about "a snowball effect" and its various synonyms on our sister site, the [English Language & Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256232/word-phrase-that-means-a-series-of-problems-of-increasing-severity-caused-by-a-s/256234).

Answer (score 1):

In situations where

> **A** caused **B** caused **C** caused **D**

this can be described as a

> chain of events

since thy are continuous like links on a chain, or possibly

> related events

Comment: May I say `I didn't fix the ceiling water leakage yet, it is an unfortunate chain of events that may require more time`?

Comment: Essentially, yes, you could say that, but it would be better to have more context around your sentence, since the "chain of events" is not what requires more time. You could say "An unfortunate chain of events has prevented me from fixing the ceiling leak" meaning things have happened to prevent you from fixing it.

Comment: @nowox, note that in Peter's sample sentence, "fixing the leak" is the end of the chain. However, based on your sample sentence, it sounds like fixing the leak is the beginning, so, I would probably say, "I haven't fixed the leak in the ceiling yet because it *will lead to* a chain of events that may require more time."